# Controller undefined when declared in a single module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is something I don't fully understand with AngularJS. If I declare the controllers this way:

```
angular.module('ngApp', []).controller('AboutCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.awesomeThings = ['HTML5 Boilerplate', 'AngularJS', 'Karma'];
}]);

angular.module('ngApp', []).controller('ContactCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.awesomeThings = ['HTML5 Boilerplate', 'AngularJS', 'Karma'];
}]);

angular.module('ngApp', []).controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.awesomeThings = ['HTML5 Boilerplate', 'AngularJS', 'Karma'];
}]);
```

...whenever I try to test them only one of them pass the test case(s):

```
describe('MainCtrl', function () {
  var scope;

  beforeEach(module('ngApp'));
  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller('MainCtrl', { $scope: scope });
  }));

  it('should attach a list of `awesomeThings` to the scope', function () {
    expect(scope.awesomeThings.length).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

(I have also three files with the same test case repeated, the only thing that changes is the controller name: `AboutCtrl` and `ContactCtrl` in the apprpriate locations).

On the other hand, if I say: `var app = angular.module('ngApp', []);` and then "attach" the controllers to it, everything works fine. The same if I attached them to the same chain in one `angular.module('ngApp', []).controller(/* ... */).controller(/* ... */);`

The reason I want them separate is because I want to have them in (three...N) different files.

Anyone has any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-declaring your `ngApp` module each time, rather than getting the already declared module.

From John Papa's [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y023):

> •Only set once and get for all other instances.
>
> Why?: A module should only be created once, then retrieved from that point and after.
>
> ```
> /* recommended */
>
> // to set a module
> angular.module('app', []);
>
> // to get a module
> angular.module('app');
> ```

Answer (score 1):

By calling `angular.module('ngApp', [])` you are creating a new module, not reusing the same one. In order to do that just call `.module` with the app name and no other argument

angular.module('ngApp')

**file1.js**

```
angular.module('ngApp').controller(...);
```

**file2.js**

```
angular.module('ngApp').controller(...);
```

you could also just save the module to a global variable and just use that variable

**main.js**

var app = angular.module('ngApp',[]);

**file1.js**

```
app.controller(...);
```

**file2.js**

```
app.controller(...);
```